# File replication in a workgroup environment

Tags: windows-server-2008, replication, synchronization

I have two web servers where I need to sync some folders. I'd like to use Windows Distributed File System Replication (DFSR), but the servers are in a workgroup environment, which is not supported by DFSR.

Can anyone recommend other tools which can be used to achieve the same?

Comment: Are you runnning windows or linux? And what is DFSR? Presumably a Windows environment since you talk about workgroups, but are the servers running Windows too?

Comment: Yes, the servers are all running Windows 2008 server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an account with the same username and password on both systems. Make a share on the one being replicated to. Run robocopy /Mir in a scheduled job under that user account. Bam, poor-man's replication.

Comment: Master/slave.  Make changes to the master only and never the slave.